# Concurrency Primitives in Scala

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka, atomic

What would be a good concurrency primitives for accessing of an object that is CPU bound(without IO and Networking)?

For example, there's a FooCounter, which has a methods get(), set() and inc() for var counter: Int, that being shared among thousands and millions of threads.

```
object FooCounter{
  var counter: Int = 0;
  def get() = counter
  def set(value: Int) = {counter = counter + value} 
  def inc() = counter + 1
}
```

I found that most literature on Scala is oriented about Akka. For me it seems that Actor model is not really suitable for this task.

There's also Futures/Promises but they are good for blocking tasks.

In Java there's a good primitive Atomics that uses latches, which is pretty robust and descent for this task.

**Update:**
I can use Java primitives for this simple task. However, my objective to use and learn Scala Concurrency model on this simple example.

Comment: Haven't quite got time for a full answer, but you're right that Akka isn't really the right thing for this. Take a look at http://nbronson.github.io/scala-stm/ - it implements Software Transactional Memory, which works precisely for this scenario. I think it's going to be added to the Scala standard library.

Comment: "millions of threads" ...  Sure

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be aware that your implementation of `FooCounter` is not thread-safe. If multiple threads simultaneously invoke the `get`, `set` and `inc` methods, there is no guarantee that the count will be accurate. You should use one of the following utilities to implement a correct concurrent counter:

- `synchronized` statement (Scala `synchronized` statement is similar to the [one in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html))
- [atomic variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html)
- STMs (for example, [ScalaSTM](http://nbronson.github.io/scala-stm/))
- potentially, you could use an Akka actor that is a counter, but note that this is not the most straightforward application of actors

Other Scala concurrency utilities, such as futures and promises, parallel collections or reactive extensions, are not the best fit for implementing a concurrent counter, and have different usages.

You should know that Scala in some cases reuses the Java concurrency infrastructure. For example - Scala does not provide atomic variables of its own, since Java atomic classes already do the job. Instead, Scala aims to provide higher-level concurrency abstractions, such as actors, STMs and asynchronous event streams.

### Benchmarking

To assess the running time and efficiency of your implementation, a good choice is [ScalaMeter](http://scalameter.github.io/). The online documentation at the website contains detailed examples on how to do benchmarking.

### Documentation and concurrency libraries

While Akka is the most popular and best documented Scala concurrency utility, there are many other high quality implementations, some of which are more appropriate for different tasks:

- [futures and promises](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html)
- [parallel collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html) and [ScalaBlitz](http://scala-blitz.github.io/home/documentation/)
- [software transactional memory](http://nbronson.github.io/scala-stm/)
- [reactive extensions](http://rxscala.github.io/)

I think [Learning Concurrent Programming in Scala](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/learning-concurrent-programming-scala) might be a good book for you. It contains detailed documentation of different concurrency styles in Scala, as well as directions on when to use which. Chapters 5 and 9 also deal with benchmarking.
Specifically, a **concurrent counter** utility is described, optimized, and made scalable in the Chapter 9 of the book.

Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've already pre-ordered a book. Looking forward to read when it would be available.

Answer (score 4):

You can use all Java syntonization primitives, like AtomicInteger for example for counting.

For more complicated tasks I personally like scala-stm library: http://nbronson.github.io/scala-stm/

With STM your example will look like this

```
object FooCounter{
  private val counter = Ref(0);
  def get() = atomic { implicit txn => counter() }
  def set(value: Int) = atomic { implicit txn => counter() = counter() + value } 
  def inc() = atomic { implicit txn => counter() = counter() + 1 }
}
```

However for this simple example I would stop on Java primitives.

Comment: Agree, I can use Java primitives but my objective is use Scala APIs and learn them. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: BTW would it be a good choice to make counter immutable and set it with CopyOnWrite pattern?

Answer (score 3):

You are right about the "Akka orientation" in Scala: all in all I think there is a pretty overlap of Scala Language developer community and Akka ones. Late versions of Scala relies on Akka actors for concurrency, but frankly I cannot see anithing bad in this.

Regarding your question, to cite "Akka in Action" book:

> Actors are great for processing many messages, capturing state and
>   reacting with different behaviors based on the messages they receive"

and

> "Futures are the tool to use when you would rather use functions and
>   don't really need objects to do the job"

A Future is a placeholder for a value not yet available, so even if it is used for non blocking tasks, it's useful for more than that and I think it could be your choice here.

Comment: I need to look at Akka more precisely. My understanding of Akka is to cumbersome to setup Akka cluster, routes for this simple task. Could you please elaborate how future can guard my value against of thousands threads?

Comment: You don't need clustering or routing if you're just running concurrent tasks within the same JVM.  That's why `akka-cluster` and `akka-remoting` are separate dependencies from the core `akka-actor` library.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not willing to use `java.util.concurrent` directly, then your most elegant solution may be using [Akka Agents](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/agents.html).

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import akka.agent.Agent

class FooCounter {
  val counter = Agent(0)
  def get() = counter()
  def set(v: Int) = counter.send(v)
  def inc() = counter.send(_ + 1)
  def modify(f: Int => Int) = counter.send(f(_))
}
```

This is asynchronous, and guarantees sequentiality of operations. The semantics are nice, and if you need more performance, you can always change it to the good old `java.util.concurrent` analogue:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger

class FooCounter {
  val counter = new AtomicInteger(0)
  def get() = counter.get()
  def set(v: Int) = counter.set(v)
  def inc() = counter.incrementAndGet()
  def modify(f: Int => Int) = {
    var done = false
    var oldVal: Int = 0
    while (!done) {
      oldVal = counter.get()
      done = counter.compareAndSet(oldVal, f(oldVal))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: fyi Agents are deprecated

Answer (score 2):

One of possible solutions of your task is actors. It is not fastest solution but safe and simple:

```
sealed trait Command
case object Get extends Command
case class Inc(value: Int) extends Command

class Counter extends Actor {
  var counter: Int = 0

  def receive = {
    case Get =>
      sender ! counter
    case Inc(value: Int) =>
      counter += value
      sender ! counter
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger` works very nicely with Scala, makes counting threadsafe, and you don't have to put additional dependencies into your project.